# Can ISP detect my router easily if I use only Wireless devices out of it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I am curious to know that can ISP detect my router easily if I use only Wireless devices through Wifi which includes Laptop, PC, Android Devices(having different Ip configuration)out of it or they will notice any change in Ip address. I would really appreciate if you take me out of this headache as I know nothing about that kind of stuff.(TP-Link TL-WR740N router)

Comment: You shouldn't worry about your ISP detecting the use of a router, but if they can detect your router, not using the LAN capabilties won't change their ability to detect your router.

Comment: If you use your *router* only as wireless access point and do not connect it to your ISPs modem then there is no way yor ISP can detect it. Since this seems rather obvious I wonder if I have a problem understanding just what you wanted to ask.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  The types of devices connected to the router have no effect on whether the ISP can detect the router.  Why do you care if the ISP detects your router?

Answer (score 1):

If you a modem (ADSL modem, fibre modem, cable modem) and behind that your own wireless access point then no, your ISP has no access to it and cannot detect how you use it.

In pictures:

```
                          Combo device with
 Your devices:   (|)      Wireless, router, ----- wire ----- Your modem.
                          switch etc etc
```

If you use a single device with includes the modem, the router, the wireless access point, the DNS server, the DHCP server, a firewall, an access pooints, ... (often incorrectly simplified to *a router*) then it depends.

- If the ISP supplied the device and added its own backdoor or own user/pass then they can detect what you do with it. Note that 'can' and 'will actively do that' are quite different.
- If they did not add a backdoor or if you use your own *router* then they cannot.

Ofc. this assumes that the *routers* are not vulnerable to anyone on the Internet facing side. Something which should be true but which sadly not always it the case.  The recentl vulnerabilities in some netgear *router* is a good example if it, but it can happen with any manufacturer. Basically you should need to check for firmware updates for your device, and see if they fix security vulnerabilities. Most people do not do this, which is one of the reasons ISP add their own accounts and with that the ability to remotely update.

Comment: If I connect the internet cable from ISP to WAN port of router then ?(**easy** detection by ISP without scanning or any thing like this)

Comment: Then they should see nothing more than the MAC address of your WAN port. They should not be able to see anything behind that.

Comment: If I connect PC through LAN ports of router then? They would see any Ip dublication?

Comment: No, they only see the ISP side of the modem. Not what is on the otherside of the router/firewall.